# How to convert DATA CONTRACT to Client objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, automapper, datacontract

We have one old application that is developed using asp.net web forms and asmx services. While developing that developer have created one class library with data objects and it is referenced both in Service layer and as well as client layer and to avoid the Data conversion while passing data from service to client vice versa they have modified service proxies (reference.cs) manually so whenever we update the service reference we have to go to service proxies and remove the data objects that is been generated by wsdl.

Now we are in the process of converting those ASMX services to WCF and we don’t want to do manual editions in service proxies like earlier so I have to build some kind of data conversion methods to transfer data from data contract objects to UI Models and vice versa.

Can anyone advise me what would be the better approach to achieve above? We have many complex class objects(approximately 3 to 4 level deep).

I have tried AUTOMAPPER to do but Automapper is trying to map values to **.specified properties that are generated by service proxies and i have approximately 20-30 properties in classes mapping logic becoming very huge.

Comment: WCF can do most things for you like generating the proxy client in ServiceReference.I dont understand what more you actually need to achieve.And could you tell us what you are manually updating in the proxies?

Comment: Thank you for u r reply Andrew..Lets say if we exposing some data object through service it will create that object on service proxy so on client side that data contract comes with some service.dataContract name space.to avoid all thatwhat my previous developers did was they removed Auto generated contract objects and included actual Data objects class library namespace.so when the data is being transmitted to client from service data will behave like it is coming from class library name space not from some service.dataobject..

Comment: and they are referencing that class library in UI so they dont have to worry about Data conversion from one namespace to another namespace(DTO).I dont know what was the intention to do this..

Comment: Now i want to use DTO concept on client side instead of using Auto genarated classes.Lets say service method returned some EMPLOYEE class and i want to convert that to UIEmployee object though it has same properties.so that UI woont be impacted even though if we are doing changes on data contracts.

Comment: Wait for a moment and I will reply you. On lesson now  :-O

Comment: @AndrewCar: Did u get a chance to look into this again..